# flask-admin How to customize delete button

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, admin, flask-admin

[I want to customize the delete button In flask admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLMU2.png)

Here I have logged in through credential of aakash ,who is an admin.
Asish is normal user and pravin is super admin.
AAkash can delete normal user but he can not delete superadmin.In short i want to remove the delete button
beside pravin and give delete button beside asish.how to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hiding fields in Flask-Admin depending on logged in user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37532988/hiding-fields-in-flask-admin-depending-on-logged-in-user)

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51982429/6682517). It is about edit rights but the same solution is applicable to delete action. The only catch: you need to define your own access conditions — how to identify who can delete which data row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use if condition and check whether the user is normal user, superuser or admin. If the user is admin then you check who are the normal users and make a array and store the normal users. Now you can use a loop to loop the normal users array which we created. In side of the loop you can show your delete button because they are normal users which you want to give a delete button.